# SQL Database 'Project_Content' on SQL Server instance 'XXX' not found - after removing project server

Tags: central-administration, administration, project-server

I keep getting this error in event viewer.
I reckon project server was installed before on the farm and it has been removed but it seems its still looking for the content database see error below

```
SQL Database 'Project_Content' on SQL Server instance 'XXX' not found. 
Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

Cannot open database "Project_Content" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user XXX\xx.farm'.
```

How can i stop this and where can i inform the SP farm that it doesn't exist anymore.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Last year I had an issue with similar orphaned SharePoint databases. It was solved via the following PowerShell script:

```
Get-SPDatabase | ? { -not $_.Exists } | % { $_.Delete() }
```

I suggest you to create a backup at least from the config DB before you execute the script.

I suggest too, to check wich DBs would be deleted by the Cmdlet (the ones, that no more on SQL Server exist). You can check it via the following script (name and type of the DBs will be listed):

```
Get-SPDatabase | ? { -not $_.Exists } | % { $_.Name, $_.Type, '' }
```

Comment: Thanks I knew PS would have some options. To be o the save side wouldn't be easier to run the cmd to list the database first before deleting it. Can PS do that?